# Fire function when input[range] value changes / thumb dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm wanting to fire a function whenever a input[range] value changes, however, I also want to fire this same function when the range thumb is dragged.

[This example should make it clear.](http://jsbin.com/diganuqiba/2/edit)

The above example works fine, however I feel `.on("click mousemove",` is incredibly taxing on the DOM. Is there a better method of achieving the above without hitting the DOM on every mouse movement?

```
$('body').on("click mousemove", ".cropSlider", function() {

  var self = $(this),
      val = self.val(),
      min = self.attr('min'),
      max = self.attr('max'),
      pos = Math.round(((val - min) / (max - min)) * 100);


   style = "background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue "+pos+"%, #eee 7%);";

    console.log(pos);

  $('.cropSlider').attr('style', style);
});


<div class="default">
            <div class="cropMain" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>
            <input class="cropSlider" type="range" value="1" min="1" max="4" step=".01">
        </div>
```

*EDIT: You may have to hit "run JS" on the example link, for the blue progress bar to show. Strange behaviour JSBin.*

Comment: you're trying to change the background color? I am not quite understanding your example.

Comment: When the slider is dragged, a blue progress bar will be shown to the left of the thumb icon. This will only work in chrome atm, as I haven't added the correct prefixes

Comment: If you are worried about binding a mousemove event to the whole body – then why not be more specific in the element(s) you bind that handler to in the first place? `$('.cropSlider').on("click mousemove", function() { … });` works exactly the same for your example, but tracks mouse movement only when it is actually happening over the input element, and not “everywhere”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type=range]').on("input", function() {
 // blah
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try This
$('#cropSlider').change(function(){
     //  Your Code
});
```

Comment: This doesn't sort the issue of when the range thumb is dragged. It'll fire after it's stopped dragging.